# Sphinx4: How can improve the accuracy of recognizing wav file in dialog demo

Tags: java, netbeans, wav, sphinx4

I have edited the dialog code to make it work for my project.

1. I have created a text file with some of the possible sentences to be used in my work. I added the link in the comment section.
2. I have followed the steps on http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm to build my language model using web service.
3. then, I edited the dialog code to be:

   ```
   package dialog;

   import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
   import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
   import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.InputStream;

   public class EmployeeCode {

   private static final String ACOUSTIC_MODEL = "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us";
   private static final String DICTIONARY_PATH = "models/language/TAR0779/0779.dic";
   private static final String LANGUAGE_MODEL = "models/language/TAR0779/0779.lm";


   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       System.out.println("Loading models...");

       Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
       configuration.setAcousticModelPath(ACOUSTIC_MODEL);
       configuration.setDictionaryPath(DICTIONARY_PATH);
       configuration.setLanguageModelPath(LANGUAGE_MODEL);

       StreamSpeechRecognizer lmRecognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

       InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/ha/NetBeansProjects/Dialog/WAV/sample1.wav"));

       lmRecognizer.startRecognition(stream);
       SpeechResult result;    

       while ((result = lmRecognizer.getResult()) != null)
       {
           System.out.println("You said: " + result.getHypothesis() + '\n');
       } /* else
       {
           System.out.println("There is no stream.");  
       } */

       lmRecognizer.stopRecognition();

   }
   ```

   }
4. after run the output is:

   run:
   Loading models...
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: *+NSN+
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: *+SPN+
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: AA
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: AE
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: AH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: AO
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: AW
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: AY
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: B
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: CH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: D
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: DH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: EH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: ER
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: EY
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: F
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: G
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: HH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: IH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: IY
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: JH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: K
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: L
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: M
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: N
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: NG
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: OW
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: OY
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: P
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: R
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: S
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: SH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: T
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: TH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: UH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: UW
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: V
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: W
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: Y
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: Z
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:10 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager getUnit
   INFO: CI Unit: ZH
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:11 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.AutoCepstrum initDataProcessors
   INFO: Cepstrum component auto-configured as follows: autoCepstrum {MelFrequencyFilterBank, Denoise, DiscreteCosineTransform2, Lifter}
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:11 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.TextDictionary allocate
   INFO: Loading dictionary from: file:models/language/TAR0779/0779.dic
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.TextDictionary allocate
   INFO: Loading filler dictionary from: jar:file:/Users/ha/Downloads/sphinx4-data-1.0-20150223.210601-7-sources.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us/noisedict
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Sphinx3Loader logInfo
   INFO: Loading tied-state acoustic model from: jar:file:/Users/ha/Downloads/sphinx4-data-1.0-20150223.210601-7-sources.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Pool logInfo
   INFO: Pool means Entries: 16128
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Pool logInfo
   INFO: Pool variances Entries: 16128
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Pool logInfo
   INFO: Pool transition_matrices Entries: 42
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Pool logInfo
   INFO: Pool senones Entries: 5126
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.GaussianWeights logInfo
   INFO: Gaussian weights: mixture_weights. Entries: 15378
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Pool logInfo
   INFO: Pool senones Entries: 5126
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Sphinx3Loader logInfo
   INFO: Context Independent Unit Entries: 42
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.HMMManager logInfo
   INFO: HMM Manager: 137095 hmms
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:12 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.TiedStateAcousticModel logInfo
   INFO: CompositeSenoneSequences: 0
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:13 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.HMMPool dumpInfo
   INFO: Max CI Units 43
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:13 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.HMMPool dumpInfo
   INFO: Unit table size 79507
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:13 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.TimerPool showTimesShortTitle
   INFO: # ----------------------------- Timers----------------------------------------
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:13 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.TimerPool showTimesShortTitle
   INFO: # Name               Count   CurTime   MinTime   MaxTime   AvgTime   TotTime
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:13 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Timer showTimesShort
   INFO: Load AM              1       3.0410s   3.0410s   3.0410s   3.0410s   3.0410s
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:13 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Timer showTimesShort
   INFO: Load Dictionary      1       0.0520s   0.0520s   0.0520s   0.0520s   0.0520s
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:13 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Timer showTimesShort
   INFO: Compile              1       1.8290s   1.8290s   1.8290s   1.8290s   1.8290s
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:17 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.SpeedTracker showAudioUsage
   INFO:    This  Time Audio: 0.95s  Proc: 3.15s  Speed: 3.32 X real time
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:17 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.SpeedTracker showAudioSummary
   INFO:    Total Time Audio: 0.95s  Proc: 3.15s 3.32 X real time
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:17 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker calculateMemoryUsage
   INFO:    Mem  Total: 212.50 Mb  Free: 70.12 Mb
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:17 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker calculateMemoryUsage
   INFO:    Used: This: 142.38 Mb  Avg: 142.38 Mb  Max: 142.38 Mb
   You said: WHAT IS

   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:20 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.SpeedTracker showAudioUsage
   INFO:    This  Time Audio: 0.96s  Proc: 2.45s  Speed: 2.55 X real time
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:20 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.SpeedTracker showAudioSummary
   INFO:    Total Time Audio: 1.91s  Proc: 5.60s 2.93 X real time
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:20 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker calculateMemoryUsage
   INFO:    Mem  Total: 237.00 Mb  Free: 141.00 Mb
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:20 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker calculateMemoryUsage
   INFO:    Used: This: 96.00 Mb  Avg: 119.19 Mb  Max: 142.38 Mb
   You said: MANY MEN

   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.SpeedTracker showAudioUsage
   INFO:    This  Time Audio: 1429182208.00s  Proc: 1.19s  Speed: 0.00 X real time
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.SpeedTracker showAudioSummary
   INFO:    Total Time Audio: 1429182208.00s  Proc: 6.79s 0.00 X real time
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker calculateMemoryUsage
   INFO:    Mem  Total: 247.50 Mb  Free: 144.35 Mb
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker calculateMemoryUsage
   INFO:    Used: This: 103.15 Mb  Avg: 113.84 Mb  Max: 142.38 Mb
   You said: MANY

   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.TimerPool showTimesShortTitle
   INFO: # ----------------------------- Timers----------------------------------------
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.TimerPool showTimesShortTitle
   INFO: # Name               Count   CurTime   MinTime   MaxTime   AvgTime   TotTime
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Timer showTimesShort
   INFO: Load AM              1       3.0410s   3.0410s   3.0410s   3.0410s   3.0410s
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Timer showTimesShort
   INFO: Load Dictionary      1       0.0520s   0.0520s   0.0520s   0.0520s   0.0520s
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Timer showTimesShort
   INFO: Score                586     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.2270s   0.0031s   1.8140s
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Timer showTimesShort
   INFO: Prune                2043    0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0020s   0.0000s   0.0280s
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Timer showTimesShort
   INFO: Grow                 2051    0.0000s   0.0000s   0.9200s   0.0025s   5.1330s
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Timer showTimesShort
   INFO: Frontend             298     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.2100s   0.0009s   0.2640s
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Timer showTimesShort
   INFO: Compile              1       1.8290s   1.8290s   1.8290s   1.8290s   1.8290s
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.SpeedTracker showAudioSummary
   INFO:    Total Time Audio: 1429182208.00s  Proc: 6.79s 0.00 X real time
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker calculateMemoryUsage
   INFO:    Mem  Total: 247.50 Mb  Free: 141.87 Mb
   Apr 16, 2015 2:04:21 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker calculateMemoryUsage
   INFO:    Used: This: 105.63 Mb  Avg: 111.79 Mb  Max: 142.38 Mb
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 28 seconds)

The correct result should be: **what is the minimum salary.**

my wav file is: https://www.mediafire.com/?khgyc9bhltz0z3b

How can I improve the accuracy of my wav file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: here is my corpus: https://www.mediafire.com/?boil55ly65551k6

Comment: here is my new corpus: https://www.mediafire.com/?boil55ly65551k6

Comment: You need to remove punctuation (dots) from corpus before lm training.

Answer (score 1):

> private static final String ACOUSTIC_MODEL = "models/acoustic/wsj";

This is wrong, you need to use default en-us model

> I have deleted a lot of lines of missing a phonetic transcription for words in my corpus

The corpus must be a text file, not RTF file. You need to try to create language model and dictionary again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Nikolay-Shmyrev. I have edited the code in my question and the output have changed too. can you please help me?

Comment: I have no idea what you corrupted there, I suggest you to start from a clean demo again and make your changes.

Comment: Thank you @nikolay-shmyrev. The error raised after I added en-us model as an acoustic model. also I changed the dictionary path. when I but them back as: private static final String ACOUSTIC_MODEL = "models/acoustic/wsj";private static final String DICTIONARY_PATH = "models/acoustic/wsj/dict/cmudict.0.6d";private static final String LANGUAGE_MODEL = "models/language/TAR7772/7772.lm"; The code works with the very law accuracy. Any help please?

Comment: You are not using latest sphinxtrain as suggested by tutorial http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4, you are not using latest models from that sphinxtrain

Comment: I am using the latest version of them. what shall I change?

Comment: Those are wrong. You can find link to the proper one in tutorial

Comment: Thank you. Here is the new jars: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MhYjV.png . I still get the same output, what shall I do. I really need to do it today so sorry for the inconvenience :$

Comment: I have no idea what sphinx-0.7 is doing in your classpath. It is not correct jar. You also need to update with the code you have and result you get.

Comment: and deleted sphinx-0.7 jar

Comment: You need to remove punctuation (dots) from corpus before lm training.

Comment: I have edited the code and the output in my question. We are now back to my main question, improving the accuracy. I'm using sphinx in my master thesis and with this result it will give a very law percentage which I believe it does not. Any help?

Comment: You need to add a loop to retrieve multiple results, not just the first result. Then it will decode not just the beginning of your phrase

Comment: I did add the loop but nothing has improved. if I wanted to refer to some methods to improve the accuracy in my thesis what do you suggest?

Comment: You need to learn to be more precise. What do you mean by "nothing has improved"? What is the result?

Comment: I'm sorry. I did edited the question and the output. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your loop is wrong. See transcriber demo source to see how to make a loop.

Comment: I edited the loop and the result again. Still the result are not what I expect. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: I will appreciate your reply very much... Thanks